# Getting SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, session

I am working with Hibernate session and I am basically trying to update the table but at the same time before updating I need to make sure if that insert entry is not already there in the table. 
Note : this is basically a cron job which will run on daily basis and I just need to insert new record based on some logic.

Here is the snippet of my code:

```
    ... 
    ....

    ScrollableResults scroll = 
                crit.addOrder(Order.asc("expireDate"))
                .scroll();   // this will give list on daily basis which I need to filter out
            session.beginTransaction();
            Query query = session.createQuery("from SD"); 

            List<SD> sdObjectList= query.list(); // This is to do select statement so I can compare the list with new entry in while loop below
            List<String> sdList= new ArrayList<String>();  // to hold only strings extracted frm sdObjectList

            for(SD sd: sdObjectList) {
                sdList.add(sd.getName());
            }
            session.beginTransaction();
            while(scroll.next()) {        // --> This line throws error 
                Foo foo_obj = (Foo) scroll.get(0);
                // foo_obj will have unique id as well as name
                if (sdList.contains(foo_obj.getName())) {
                    out.println("**SKIPPING foo_obj, since already in DB " + foo_obj.getName());
                    continue;
                }
                SD sd= new SD(); 
                SD.setdID(foo_obj.getId());
                SD.setName(foo_obj.getName());
                SD.setStatus("xyz");
                session.save(SD);

                FooObjList.add(foo_obj);
            }   
            //Commit the transaction
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            scroll.close();
```

Here is the error :

```
   [java] Jun 16, 2020 10:52:32 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
     [java] WARNING: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1000
     [java] Jun 16, 2020 10:52:32 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
     [java] SEVERE: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
     [java] org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not advance using next()
     [java]     at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
     [java]     at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
     [java]     at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
     [java]     at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
     [java]     at org.hibernate.impl.ScrollableResultsImpl.next(ScrollableResultsImpl.java:127)
     [java]     at com.netnation.jobs.snapnames.list.GenerateList.main(GenerateList.java:199)
     [java] Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
     [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
     [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
     [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
     [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
     [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed(ResultSetImpl.java:794)
     [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:7139)
     [java]     at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet.next(NewProxyResultSet.java:2859)
     [java]     at org.hibernate.impl.ScrollableResultsImpl.next(ScrollableResultsImpl.java:122)
     [java]     ... 1 more
```

Can some one suggest how to fix? Or any other better way to handle the whole logic?

**Note:**
I just realized the two session.beginTransaction() is not throwing any error but I am not sure if its good practice and I am closing it properly? Also does hibernate session provide any other better way to achieve above scenario?

But when I remove the first session.beginTransaction(), it does throw the error above.

Comment: Don't call `beginTransaction()` twice, and call it *before* calling `scroll()`, and call `scroll.close()` *before* calling `commit()`.

Comment: sadly, its still throwing the same error. I thought adding two seperate beginTransaction() should solve it

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check if the entity exists. This is not required:

```
if (sdList.contains(foo_obj.getName())) {
    out.println("**SKIPPING foo_obj, since already in DB " + foo_obj.getName());
    continue;
}
```

Since, you are setting the primary key yourself via this:

```
SD.setdID(foo_obj.getId());
```

and you are not using any *auto-generated id tool*, when you do a `save`, `Hibernate` will check if the entity exists first via a `SELECT`. If yes, it does an `UPDATE`, if not it does an `INSERT`.

Now, until where in your WHILE loop does the first loop executes? Note, that if there is an exception thrown, you can no longer reuse that session, perhaps explaining why the ResultSet was closed.